# What are the BOOT-INF and META-INF directories in a Spring-Boot JAR?

Tags: java, spring-boot

When I open a jar package, there shows the `BOOT-INF` and `META-INF` folders, what's the function of them?

[image: 's th]

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The `META-INF` folder is the home for the `MANIFEST.MF` file. This file contains meta data about the contents of the JAR. For example, there is an entry called `Main-Class` that specifies the name of the Java class with the `static main()` for executable JAR files.

[for more details](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html)

**BOOT-INF :**
Spring Boot applications load from the `BOOT-INF` folder. Therefore the application classes must be placed in a nested `BOOT-INF/classes` directory. Dependencies should be placed in a nested `BOOT-INF/lib` directory.

[more about Spring Boot packaging](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/executable-jar.html)

Answer (score 3):

This is a single jar Spring Boot application.

In addition to the META-INF files for the loader (as in any other jar file) the application itself is placed under BOOT-INF.

Note that such a jar cannot be used as a traditional jar any more.

Comment: How to create a jar that can be used as a traditional one? Like if jar contains BOOT-INF and META-INF, we cannot use it to import classes in another project.

Comment: @KnownUnknown The locations are wrong. Consider opening a new question for this.