# JavaFX No toolkit found despite jar is bundled

Tags: javafx, apple-m1

I have a runnable jar (`drkodi-mac-aarch64.jar`), that should contain all that is needed, including the FX components.

I can successfully start the app by executing the following command:

```
java -jar drkodi-mac-aarch64.jar
```

My java installation:

```
java -version
openjdk version "18.0.1" 2022-04-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-18.0.1+10 (build 18.0.1+10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-18.0.1+10 (build 18.0.1+10, mixed mode)
```

Now, I bundle this runnable jar into a Mac App, which contains a JRE and a launcher.

```
file DrKodi.app/Contents/MacOS/launcher-macosx-aarch64.sh
DrKodi/DrKodi.app/Contents/MacOS/launcher-macosx-aarch64.sh: POSIX shell script text executable, ASCII text

cat DrKodi.app/Contents/MacOS/launcher-macosx-aarch64.sh

cd "$(dirname "$0")" || exit
../Plugins/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java -jar "../Resources/Java/drkodi-mac-aarch64.jar"
```

The JRE is located here:

```
DrKodi/DrKodi.app/Contents/PlugIns/jre/Contents/Home
```

It is created using the following command:

```
Creating JRE with next modules included: java.base,java.logging,java.desktop,jdk.unsupported,java.scripting
[INFO]         Using /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/temurin-18.jdk/Contents/Home/jmods modules directory
[INFO]         Executing command: /bin/sh -c cd '/Users/alex/sources/drkodi/.' && '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/temurin-18.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/jlink' --module-path /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/temurin-18.jdk/Contents/Home/jmods --add-modules java.base,java.logging,java.desktop,jdk.unsupported,java.scripting --output /Users/alex/sources/drkodi/target/DrKodi/DrKodi.app/Contents/PlugIns/jre/Contents/Home --no-header-files --no-man-pages --strip-debug --compress=2
[INFO]         Removing folder [/Users/alex/sources/drkodi/target/DrKodi/DrKodi.app/Contents/PlugIns/jre/Contents/Home/legal]
[INFO]     JRE bundled in /Users/alex/sources/drkodi/target/DrKodi/DrKodi.app/Contents/PlugIns/jre/Contents/Home!
```

Now, when I start the App using the bundled java executable, like this:

```
./DrKodi.app/Contents/PlugIns/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java -jar ./DrKodi.app/Contents/Resources/Java/drkodi-mac-aarch64.jar
```

I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: No toolkit found
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:280)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:291)
```

If I start the jar file using my installed JRE, like follows, it works:

```
java -jar ./DrKodi.app/Contents/Resources/Java/drkodi-mac-aarch64.jar
```

If I take a look at the runnable jar, the library seems to be there, it's also the right arch:

```
unzip -l drkodi-mac-aarch64.jar | grep javafx
     1659  10-25-2019 15:22   BOOT-INF/lib/javafx-weaver-spring-boot-starter-1.3.0.jar
     5686  10-25-2019 15:23   BOOT-INF/lib/javafx-weaver-spring-1.3.0.jar
     9621  10-25-2019 15:23   BOOT-INF/lib/javafx-weaver-core-1.3.0.jar
     3918  10-25-2019 15:24   BOOT-INF/lib/javafx-weaver-spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.0.jar
      302  10-17-2022 11:07   BOOT-INF/lib/javafx-fxml-19.jar
   129499  09-12-2022 11:46   BOOT-INF/lib/javafx-fxml-19-mac-aarch64.jar
      306  10-17-2022 11:07   BOOT-INF/lib/javafx-controls-19.jar
  2547893  09-12-2022 11:46   BOOT-INF/lib/javafx-controls-19-mac-aarch64.jar
      306  10-17-2022 11:07   BOOT-INF/lib/javafx-graphics-19.jar
  4812958  09-12-2022 11:46   BOOT-INF/lib/javafx-graphics-19-mac-aarch64.jar
      302  10-17-2022 11:07   BOOT-INF/lib/javafx-base-19.jar
   752442  09-12-2022 11:36   BOOT-INF/lib/javafx-base-19-mac-aarch64.jar
```

This is strange to me, since the bundled JRE was created from my local Java installation, it should be the same.

The JavaFX libs are inside the runnable jar, the app is not modular, so it is a little strange that it works one way but not the other.

I am on a Mac M1.

Modules known to my installed JRE:

```
java --list-modules

java.base@18.0.1
java.compiler@18.0.1
java.datatransfer@18.0.1
java.desktop@18.0.1
java.instrument@18.0.1
java.logging@18.0.1
java.management@18.0.1
java.management.rmi@18.0.1
java.naming@18.0.1
java.net.http@18.0.1
java.prefs@18.0.1
java.rmi@18.0.1
java.scripting@18.0.1
java.se@18.0.1
java.security.jgss@18.0.1
java.security.sasl@18.0.1
java.smartcardio@18.0.1
java.sql@18.0.1
java.sql.rowset@18.0.1
java.transaction.xa@18.0.1
java.xml@18.0.1
java.xml.crypto@18.0.1
jdk.accessibility@18.0.1
jdk.attach@18.0.1
jdk.charsets@18.0.1
jdk.compiler@18.0.1
jdk.crypto.cryptoki@18.0.1
jdk.crypto.ec@18.0.1
jdk.dynalink@18.0.1
jdk.editpad@18.0.1
jdk.hotspot.agent@18.0.1
jdk.httpserver@18.0.1
jdk.incubator.foreign@18.0.1
jdk.incubator.vector@18.0.1
jdk.internal.ed@18.0.1
jdk.internal.jvmstat@18.0.1
jdk.internal.le@18.0.1
jdk.internal.opt@18.0.1
jdk.internal.vm.ci@18.0.1
jdk.internal.vm.compiler@18.0.1
jdk.internal.vm.compiler.management@18.0.1
jdk.jartool@18.0.1
jdk.javadoc@18.0.1
jdk.jcmd@18.0.1
jdk.jconsole@18.0.1
jdk.jdeps@18.0.1
jdk.jdi@18.0.1
jdk.jdwp.agent@18.0.1
jdk.jfr@18.0.1
jdk.jlink@18.0.1
jdk.jpackage@18.0.1
jdk.jshell@18.0.1
jdk.jsobject@18.0.1
jdk.jstatd@18.0.1
jdk.localedata@18.0.1
jdk.management@18.0.1
jdk.management.agent@18.0.1
jdk.management.jfr@18.0.1
jdk.naming.dns@18.0.1
jdk.naming.rmi@18.0.1
jdk.net@18.0.1
jdk.nio.mapmode@18.0.1
jdk.random@18.0.1
jdk.sctp@18.0.1
jdk.security.auth@18.0.1
jdk.security.jgss@18.0.1
jdk.unsupported@18.0.1
jdk.unsupported.desktop@18.0.1
jdk.xml.dom@18.0.1
jdk.zipfs@18.0.1
```

Modules known to the bundled JRE:

```
DrKodi.app/Contents/PlugIns/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java --list-modules

java.base@18.0.1
java.datatransfer@18.0.1
java.desktop@18.0.1
java.logging@18.0.1
java.prefs@18.0.1
java.scripting@18.0.1
java.xml@18.0.1
jdk.unsupported@18.0.1
```

The App uses [javafx-weaver](https://github.com/rgielen/javafx-weaver), so it is basically a Desktop Spring Boot application.

Comment: What is the "bundled" jre?  Why are JavaFX components listed when you type `ls` and where are they?  Why not in the app image or on the module path? What is in the jar and why would the jar have an architecture?  Why not package the app the "standard" way, using `jlink` or `jpackage`?  Is the app modular or non-modular?  How did you build the jar and how does it know what the class with `main` is?  Is the class with `main` a JavaFX `Application`?  What is the complete stack trace for the error?  If you wish, you can edit the question to add additional info, rather than respond in comments.

Comment: If you are going to package the app as an installable app, it would seem best to package it using `jpackage`.  Third-party tools like [JPackageScriptFX](https://github.com/dlemmermann/JPackageScriptFX) or [badass runtime](https://badass-runtime-plugin.beryx.org/releases/latest/) can help, though it can be complex.

Comment: To adopt your current approach, [download the jmods](https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/) (select type `jmods`) and link them into your image as part of your jlink command, listing the JavaFX modules you use.  This will make the JavaFX runtime part of the custom JRE you have assembled for your distribution.  Then you do not (and should not) include JavaFX jars in the distribution path for your application, also you don't need to explicitly add module paths to JavaFX as VM parameters when your app is run (which you would otherwise need to do).  Your app jar is arch independent.

Comment: Many thanks for the suggestions, I still dont understand why its failing.
in both cases the app is started the same way, its just another Java executable.

Comment: I didn't know what `BOOT-INF` was, so I had to [look it up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57034083/what-are-the-boot-inf-and-meta-inf-directories-in-a-spring-boot-jar) -> "Spring Boot applications load from the BOOT-INF folder."

Comment: JavaFX should not be on the classpath, it isn't supported. Even if it worked, I guess you get a sys err log message that it isn't supported, `"WARNING: Unsupported JavaFX configuration: classes were loaded from 'unnamed module @14c24f4c'"`.  JavaFX should be run as modules on the module path, and Spring Boot (even 3) isn't going to be able to run modules from the BOOT-INF folder (my guess).  If instead the modules are on the module path or in the base image, that is a supported runtime configuration and should work.

Comment: The app uses https://github.com/rgielen/javafx-weaver, which is a really neat and slim way to bring together to great frameworks.

Comment: Yeah, the weaver thing would be fine, since your app is not modular, you can just have the boot packaging which places it and other dependent libs into the `BOOT-INF` directory and get them off the classpath.  The only thing you need to be careful of is the JavaFX libs, which should be on the module path.  The tricky thing is that weaver has compile dependencies on JavaFX.  It should have them as provided dependencies instead (IMO).  So just make sure that the JavaFX dependencies don't end up in the `BOOT-INF` for the distribution (by modifying your build scripts).

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue on Ubuntu. My project is with Java 17, Spring Boot 3 and JavaFX 20 (no Weaver though). It works well out of the box in IDEA on Mac and PC. But on Ubuntu server jar did't start due to `java.lang.RuntimeException: No toolkit found`.

I've managed to fix it adding this to `pom.xml`:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
    <version>20.0.2</version>
    <classifier>win</classifier>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
    <version>20.0.2</version>
    <classifier>linux</classifier>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
    <version>20.0.2</version>
    <classifier>mac</classifier>
</dependency>
```

Found the solution here: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#maven "Cross-platform jar" section.